# How to include a separator in the inserted data in SQL load, Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, separator

```
load data
infile 'c:\oracle_toad\sql_loader\v1_data.txt'
replace into table v1 fields terminated by ','
( a integer external, b char, c char )

1,2,"da,ta1" 
2,4,"dat,a2"
2,4,"da,ta2"

"" are not supposed to be inserted as a part of data. That's just for reference.
```

I intentionally inserted "," in each of the data set.
I am hoping to insert 1, 2, "da,ta1" <<<  like this. Is there a way that I can include the separator "," within the data set?

Comment: I think you should enclose data that includes separator in double quotes `""`

Comment: OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '", add this.

Comment: Please be advised putting more than one value in a column violates first normal form of data normalization and should be avoided if this is in your control.  It will cause problems when you need to use one of those values in a where clause for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

Test table:

```
SQL> create table test (col1 number, col2 varchar2(20), col3 varchar2(20));

Table created.
```

Control file:

```
load data 
infile *
replace
into table test
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
trailing nullcols
(
col1,
col2,
col3
)

begindata
1,2,"da,ta1" 
2,4,"dat,a2"
2,4,"da,ta2"
```

Loading session & the result:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test04.ctl log=test04.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Kol 27 14:11:26 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 2
Commit point reached - logical record count 3

SQL> select * From test;

      COL1 COL2                 COL3
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 2                    da,ta1
         2 4                    dat,a2
         2 4                    da,ta2

SQL>
```